# Enqueueing Scripts on a Custom Top-level Menu Page

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, add-menu-page

I've created a menu page using the following function:

```
add_menu_page(
'Nonpareil options',
'Nonpareil options',    
'administrator',    
'nonpareil_theme_options',  
'nonpareil_theme_display'   
);
```

Now I want to load a js file only on this page. I'm trying to do so properly by enqueueing it only on my new page:

```
function nonpareil_options_js_enqueue($hook_suffix) {
    if( 'nonpareil_theme_options' != $hook_suffix )
    return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'nonpareil-options', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/nonpareil-options.js', array('jquery') );
}       
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'nonpareil_options_js_enqueue' );
```

The script is not being enqueued. I think the issue is probably that $hook_suffix != "nonpareil_theme_options" on my new page, but in that case I have no idea what to put instead. What's wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try replacing

```
if( 'nonpareil_theme_options' != $hook )
```

with

```
if( 'toplevel_page_nonpareil_theme_options' != $hook )
```

if you have the custom menu added like this:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page');
function register_custom_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page('Nonpareil options','Nonpareil options',    'administrator',    'nonpareil_theme_options',  'nonpareil_theme_display'   );
}
```

**Edit:**

It looks like you are using this `admin_enqueue_scripts` example in the Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts#Example:_Target_a_Specific_Admin_Page

so in your case the Codex example would be like this:

```
function nonpareil_options_js_enqueue($hook) {
    if( 'toplevel_page_nonpareil_theme_options' != $hook )
    return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'nonpareil-options', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/nonpareil-options.js', array('jquery') );
}       
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'nonpareil_options_js_enqueue' );
```

In the file `/wp-admin/admin-header.php` you have the following

```
do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix);
do_action("admin_print_scripts-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_scripts');
```

so you can see the difference, `admin_print_scripts` doesn't take input, but `admin_enqueue_scripts` does (and this is the filter you are using in your code example).

If you wonder where `toplevel_page_` comes from, you can check out the source code for `get_plugin_page_hookname()` since it is generating the value for `$hook_suffix` in your case.

**Conclusion:**

Add `toplevel_page_`  in front of your menu slug.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just import a particular variable into an action by naming it in the callback function. The variable imported, if available, is the variable supplied when the `do_action` function for that hook name runs. What you call that variable inside your callback function is irrelevant.

`admin_print_scripts` does not pass a variable at all. You can prove this to yourself with this disposable function (***which will break stuff***):

```
function apx($a) {
 var_dump($a); die;
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts','apx');
```

Again, ***that will break the site***. You will have to remove the function (or at least the `die` part of it) before the admin pages will work again. I work on a development server so that is not a problem for me.

`admin_enqueue-scripts` does pass a variable, and what you are trying to do should work but requires additional logic in the function whereas doing the following does not. The logic is handled by the hook itself.

1. Visit the page you want the script enqueued on
2. View source for the page in your browser
3. Near the top there is some embedded Javascript.
4. Inside that Javascript look for `pagenow = 'some_string_resembling_the_page_slug'`
5. Enqueue on a hook named `admin_print_scripts-some_string_resembling_the_page_slug`

In your case something like:

```
function nonpareil_options_js_enqueue($hook) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'nonpareil-options', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/nonpareil-options.js', array('jquery') );
}       
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-some_string_resembling_the_page_slug', 'nonpareil_options_js_enqueue' );
```

Comment: Thank you! This also works, just not exactly what I was looking for. Everywhere I search, it seems to be recommended that admin_enqueue_scripts should be used over admin_print_scripts for loading anything other than small amounts of inline js on admin pages. Cheers.